# How to add commands to run (WIN+R) to run programs like Firefox, Sublime etc

Tags: run-dialog

How to add commands to run (WIN+R) to run programs like Firefox, Sublime etc.

I need that because I prefer keyboard to mouse, and it's faster for instance to just press WIN+R -> type `cmd` and press Enter.. I want the same for programs like sublime etc. or maybe is it possible also to open folder by typing custom command something like `open folder project` or it is something impossible?

Comment: I know it's not what you're asking for, but note that you can pin items to the start bar and open them instantly with Win+Number. If you frequently use Firefox and Sublime, this might speed things up even further for you

Comment: That's not cool enough I like clean desktop and startbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, besides "The Path"(environment variable).  There is this location in the registry.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`

[image]

Comment: Ok, to not be an egoist will mark your reply as answer :)

Comment: @AigarsCibuļskis to not be selfless I won't object ;-)

Comment: Great solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Windows Run dialog basically runs programs that exist in your path. It is great for running windows software (I use it all the time to run Notepad). It cannot be scripted, and you would need to add any folder that you have required files in, to your path, which is not really practical.

What Windows are you using?

Windows 7+ has a search in Start, so basically you press WIN key and start typing, and it starts search. It searches everything that you have in your start menu, and even more. I actually use it more than run dialog because I can press win key and start typing, and it usually finds what I need.

Before Windows 7 I was using [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/) which is highly adaptive and at the time was a great quick launch utility.

I hope you can use some of this.

Comment: You write "Windows Run dialog basically runs programs that exist in your path"  <-- NOT JUST THAT there is a registry location too.. AppPaths, and btw,  if I recall, it checks that registry location first..

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with idea of making new folder called `CUSTOM_PATH` anywhere you want. Then I edited environment variables of my window and added path to that folder. That allowed me to throw in shortcuts to programs and call them via `WIN+R`

[[image]

<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqKvS.png)

Comment: Interesting idea, but isn't this basically what the Start Menu does...?

Answer (score 0):

if someone is currently looking for it, there is an easier way: just add a shortcut to the windows rais folder and rename the shortcut with the command you want to run.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeXVj.png

FLP

Comment: Some people might prefer to put the shortcuts in a subdirectory of their user (home / profile) directory, and add that to their `PATH`. P.S. What is “rais”?